# What are some possible "functional" memory structures?

Tags: functional-programming, garbage-collection, lambda-calculus

With my thin knowledge on embedded systems, compilers, and computer architectures, I know that the basics of computer memory(physical) are sort of like an array, with addressing which work like pointers. I see that imperative programming(which eventually unwraps to assembly, or the Turing Machine) fits this architecture very well.

I am a bit interested to see if there is a counterpart of physical memory that might fit the functional programming style. By "fitting", I am making the assumption that all pure functional languages can unwrap to be immutable lambda expressions(via Lambda Calculus). Now, with the array-like memory structure, we have to allocate and gc objects under the scene in order to get lambdas to work(because lambda expressions do not address operations on memory directly). Just as a thought experiment, is it possible to have a device that fits the need of memory in lambda expressions, while not containing a garbage collector?

Yes, I know that some imperative programming languages do use garbage collectors. However, when boiled down to assembly, it doesn't. So I am more curious about the evaluation of "pure" lambda expressions.

Just as a note, the *lambda expressions* I talk about include the fixed point operator(i.e. recursion).

Comment: What do you mean by "device"? Why do you think you need garbage collection? A turing machine has infinite memory.

Comment: For "device" I mean physical memory. And, forget about the Turing Machine I just mentioned. I use the term to contrast Lambda Calculus. Think about Assembly and Lambda Expressions instead.

Comment: I think GC is needed because Lambda Expressions never manage memory. At least, not the "array" like memory we generally have. In which case, we need to find a way to allocate objects as we evaluate an expression, and destroy them after evaluation.

Comment: There's no need to destroy them. We just will run out of memory eventually for some inputs, like on every physical device. A garbage collector is an implementation detail that helps to reduce the memory requirements. It will use mutation (unlike lamda expressions) and be written in assembly (or something that compiles to it).

Comment: But what about functions that are supposed to run in constant memory? For example(in pseudo-Haskell, this sums 0 to n) `fix $ \rec (n,acc) -> if (n == 0) then acc else rec (n-1, acc+n)`. I know in array-like memory, there either need to be a GC or mutation. However, is there any storage element that can handle such thing directly? (Well, the more I write about it the more I think it is impossible... But I might be limited by my knowledge)

Comment: Well, yes: a memory device with a built-in garbage collector is an implementation of a storage type on which you can run such functions in constant memory. I guess it would need a distinction between symbols (primitive values) and pointers (objects) in its interface as well as an entry point to the reference graph. I don't know whether such has been formalised in any computational model, though. You might get better answers at [computerscience.SE] on that.

Comment: Yeah, Lambda Calculus seems much less "physical" than Turing Machine, Well, I agree CS stackexchange might be the place to go, though. Is it possible to move the question there?

Comment: *"However, is there any storage element that can handle such thing directly?"* - Time. Applying a function does not mutate in place, it mutates into the future while the past remains unchanged. Of course you will need a time machine to access past states, or absent that, make copies.

Answer (score 3):

The topic is fairly broad.

Functional hardware has been explored in e.g. [Lisp machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_machine).

More on the theoretical side, you may want to read about the various abstract machines which have been proposed for running functional languages.
Some of them are the [SECD machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SECD_machine), [the CAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_abstract_machine) (categorical), the [Krivine machine](https://www.irif.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~krivine/articles/lazymach.pdf), the [STG machine](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.53.3729).

Perhaps a more radical approach can be learnt by looking at the various graph-reduction machines. A [pioneering work](http://www2.parc.com/csl/groups/sda/publications/papers/Lamping-POPL90/for-web.pdf) by Lamping describes how lambda can be run faster by rewriting graphs (!), instead of expressions.
More recently, linear logic simplified the several rewriting rules.

Some of these approaches can give you some hint at how a custom functional hardware should be made to speed up execution.

For conventional hardware, the STG machine seems one of the most promising approaches.